# How to allow installation of Non-Market apps (ICS)?

Tags: applications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, settings, non-market

I'm attempting to install the [exynos](http://project-voodoo.org/articles/instant-fix-app-for-exynos-mem-abuse-vulnerability-no-root-required-reversible) fix after downloading the [.apk](http://dl.project-voodoo.org/apps/Voodoo-instant-anti-exynos-mem-abuse-0.9.apk) file.
When I open the file to run, the system tells me that I cannot install apps that did not originate from Google Play.

After some googling I found an article that shows a [workaround](http://www.itjungles.com/android-tips/samsung-galaxy-s2-enable-disable-unknown-sources-to-install-apk-files), however when I go to:

```
Home → Settings → Applications
```

I see a list of applications and memory usage. It's the same window I see if I go to:

```
Home → Settings → Storage → Applications
```

Ergo, I am not finding where I can tick `Unknown Sources`.

### How do I access the actual Application Settings shown below?

[image: printscreen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ICS and JB, you should find this option in `Settings  →  Security` in a section called "*Device Administration*"

[image: Unknown sources]

Comment: Thanks - got the app installed.  Says my device is not vulnerable.  Went back and unticked Unknown Sources.

Comment: Well done, it's recommended to keep unticked that option unless you are sure that all the app markets and download sites you use are really safe.

Answer (score 2):

ICS has the settings re-located and can be found under:

```
Settings  →  Security  →  Unknown Sources
```

The screen-shot present on your question is referring to Gingerbread and does not apply to ICS.